# What happened to Mephisto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source, content-management-system

So, since starting working in Ruby I've run across tons of sites ([example](http://entp.com/team/)), SO questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555785/ruby-cms-blog-mephisto-vs-radiant)), blog posts etc, that point to a "Ruby CMS" called Mephisto, using this address: http://www.mephistoblog.com/

That address is just some guy's blog with the last entry almost 3 years old. Clearly this is a dead project, but from the number of references to it in the wild I can't for the life of me find any information about what it was, why it mattered, and why it died.

Can anyone fill me in?

Lastly, I know this is only 'sort of' a ruby question... if there's a different stack exchange site I should have posted this on please let me know politely and I'll be happy to move it :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a project mainly maintained by 'technoweenie' (who now works for github). Like many things from the early days of rails, it seems to have just slowly become defunct as people have moved on.

http://techno-weenie.net/2010/6/23/you-can-let-go-now/

Answer (score 3):

[Enki](https://github.com/xaviershay/enki) is an heir of Mephisto.  It is still a living project, and many Rails bloggers are using it.  However it is for hackers, and just gives you a very blank slate to work with style-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a version of Mephisto located right here: https://github.com/mephistorb/mephisto